# SQLite for personal use

Tags: database, sqlite, desktop-application

What are the applications for your personal use that needs a small database like SQLite? I am thinking of trying a few popular databases and SQLite is surely the first one I am planning to try since I know barely nothing about database except some simple programming years ago.

I learned that SQLite is good for personal use. But embarrassingly I do not see any application except maybe managing my list of phone numbers/contact info, which has probably a few hundred items. What's your experience?

FYI, I use EndNote for my reference and softcopy of books, and I feel iTunes' music/media management is ok since I am not a frequent user anyway. And others? I do lots of coding, but I just use some simple etags tools for that. And I pretty much use .txt file (sometimes in the asciidoc style) for my notes. I have quite a bunch of notes, but not that many either.

So, really, what are your personal applications that need a small database instead of existing tools and plain text files?

Comment: A friend of mine keeps his TODO list in a SQLite database, adding, updating and deleting items using terminal and a small linux script and syncs it by storing it in his dropbox folder.

Comment: As far as I can tell Firefox uses SQLite...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any small database (think... sub 100MB) SQLite can be a valid choice. Because you can use it without much overhead it's easy to use in development.

As for tools I use (and modify whenever I miss a feature) that use SQLite:

- Couchpotato
- Sickbeard
- SabNZBD

Basically... anything that stores a list of something would be a valid candidate.

Comment: Yeah, this answers what I asked, even though I am not a user of these applications.

Answer (score 1):

There are many applications that use sqlite... Try reading the website, it has a link to "famous users", http://www.sqlite.org/famous.html

Comment: thank you for the link. I wanted to know the applications *YOU* guys use that need SQLite. Surely everyone uses Firefox, Adobe Acrabat Reader, etc.. What I meant is one's direct need for a small database (actually it does not have to do with SQLite). Sorry for my confusing question.

Comment: Does this mean that you really want to ask follow up questions? Why can't you ask those in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the focus on the term "personal use". SQLite can be used to develop profession applications. However, it doesn't provide a lot of support for a multi-user environment.

Other than that, SQLite can be used for about any type of desktop application. I wrote an MFC app for a client that tracked purchases at a gas station. It took all the purchases in from another system, and it provided a number of reports.

My Snippets application (http://www.softcircuits.com/snippets/) is in need of a rewrite and I'm going back and forth on whether or not I want the update to use SQListe.

About the only type of application that needs to store data that I wouldn't recommend to use SQLite is an app that needs to run on a server, such as a website applications.

Of course, if the data the app needs to store is so trivial that it is very easy to just load or dump it all to a file, then you really don't need a database at all.

Comment: Again, sorry for the confusion. My main point was what are your own direct need for a small database (not necessarily SQLite). I looked at your application. It looks cool. And in fact, this is probably an example of answers to my question. -- So, do you feel the need to use a small database or not? What are the pros and cons and what are the factors your decision will be based on?